# LESS in Chrome not substituting variables

Tags: html, css, macos, google-chrome, less

I am running LESS locally (or trying to). I'm running OSX, but I don't think it matters for this. I used the following to allow it to run locally:

```
/Applications/Google\ Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google\ Chrome -allow-file-access-from-files
```

I get this when the site loads:

```
less: parsed file://localhost/Users/dir/Website/ver_2/styles.less successfully. less-1.3.1.min.js:8
less: css for file://localhost/Users/dir/Website/ver_2/styles.less generated in 16ms less-1.3.1.min.js:8
less: css generated in 17ms less-1.3.1.min.js:8
```

So it seems like it's setup correctly. When I try a simple preprocessor sub, Chrome ignores it and says invalid property value in the developer tools:

```
@color: black;
body > .container{background-color: @color;}
```

Any suggestions on how to fix this?
Thank you!

Comment: Figured it out!  I needed rel="stylesheet/less" intead of just rel="stylesheet"

Comment: I suggest you answer your own question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved: needed to use rel="stylesheet/less" intead of just rel="stylesheet" when importing as . Extension (.less or .css) seems to be arbitrary.